# How to test for certain characters in a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am currently running a script with an `if` statement. Before I run the script, I want to make sure the file provided as the first argument has certain characters.

If the file does not have those certain characters in certain spots then the output would be `else "File is Invalid"` on the command line.

For the `if` statement to be true, the file needs to have at least one `hyphen` in Field 1 line 1 and at least one `comma` in Field one Line one.

How would I create an `if` statement with perhaps a test command to validate those certain characters are present?

Thanks

Im new to Linux/Unix, this is my homework so I haven't really tried anything, only brain storming possible solutions.

```
function usage
{
  echo "usage: $0 filename ..."
  echo "ERROR: $1"
}

if [ $# -eq  0 ]
then
  usage "Please enter a filename"
else
  name="Yaroslav Yasinskiy"
  echo $name
  date
  while [ $# -gt 0 ]
  do
    if [ -f $1 ]
    then
      if            <--------- here is where the answer would be
      starting_data=$1
      echo
      echo $1
        cut -f3 -d, $1 > first
        cut -f2 -d, $1 > last
        cut -f1 -d, $1 > id
        sed 's/$/:/' last > last1
        sed '/last:/ d' last1 > last2
        sed 's/^ *//' last2 > last3
        sed '/first/ d' first > first1
        sed 's/^ *//' first1 > first2
        sed '/id/ d' id > id1
        sed 's/-//g' id1 > id2
        paste -d\ first2 last3 id2 > final
        cat final
        echo ''
    else
      echo
      usage "Coult not find file $1"
    fi
    shift
  done
fi
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, within your loop you call `cut` 3-times, `sed` 7-times, `paste` once and then `cat`. You are spawning at least 12 subshells per-iteration! That is a huge indication you need to re-think your approach to the problem. I suspect the entire script could be re-written as a single call to `awk` which when running on large input files would be orders-of-magnitude more efficient. (literally, it could be the difference in the script running in 20-hours or 20-seconds) Any time in bash you see  `while ... utility1; utility2; utility3 ...` alarm bells should be going off.

Comment: While you have done a good job and provided what you have attempted and you have stated that this is homework, you really need to provide a representative input file (10-lines or so, whatever constitutes a set of input) and then what your expected output is. That is the only way anyone can make a solid recommendation to help -- though I suspect @Mig is correct and `awk` will be the proper tool for the job, without input and output it is hard to be certain. (and while `awk` and `sed` are somewhat cryptic to learn - do it, it will save you 1000-fold the time you spend learning them)

Comment: If you are familiar with perl, I'd convert the whole thing to that. If not, a cursory examination of all those `cut` and `sed` calls doesn't make me think there's anything there you couldn't probably do in one rather complicated pass with `sed`, but I'll admit I didn't try yet...

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your direct question:

> For the `if` statement to be true, the file needs to have at least one
>   `hyphen` in Field 1 line 1 and at least one `comma` in Field one Line one.
>
> How would I create an `if` statement with perhaps a test command to
>   validate those certain characters are present?

Bash provides all the tools you need. While you can call `awk`, you really just need to read the first line of the file into two-variable (say `a` and `b`) and then use the `[[ $a =~ regex ]]` to where the `regex` is an *extended* regular expression that verifies that the first field (contained in `$a`) contains both a `'-'` and `','`.

For details on the `[[ =~ ]]` expression, see [bash(1) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) under the section labeled `[[ expression ]]`.

Let's start with `read`. When  you provide two variables, `read` will read the first field (based on normal word-splitting given by `IFS` (the *Internal Field Separator*, default `$'[ \t\n]'` - space, tab, newline)). So by doing `read -r a b` you read the first field into `a` and the rest of the line into `b` (you don't care about `b` for your test)

Your `regex` can be `([-]+.*[,]+|[,]+.*[-]+)` which is an `(x|y)`, e.g. `x` OR `y` expression where `x` is `[-]+.*[,]+` (one or more `'-'` and one or more `','`), your `y` is `[,]+.*[-]+` (one or more `','` and one or more `'-'`). So by using the `'|'` your regex will accept either a `comma` then zero-or-more characters and a `hyphen` or a `hyphen` and zero-or-more characters and then a `comma` in the first field.

How do you read the line? With simple *redirection*, e.g.

```
read -r a b < "$1"
```

So your conditional test in your script would look something like:

```
if [ -f $1 ]
then
  read -r a b < "$1"
  if [[ $a =~ ([-]+.*[,]+|[,]+.*[-]+) ]]    # <-- here is where the ...
  then
    starting_data=$1
    ...
  else
    echo "File is Invalid" >&2   # redirection to 2 (stderr)
  fi
else
  echo
  usage "Coult not find file $1"
fi
shift
...
```

**Example Test Files**

```
$ cat valid
dog-food, cat-food, rabbit-food
50lb      16lb      5lb

$ cat invalid
dogfood, catfood, rabbitfood
50lb      16lb      5lb
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ read -r a b < valid
if [[ $a =~ ([-]+.*[,]+|[,]+.*[-]+) ]]; then
  echo "file valid"
else 
  echo "file invalid"
fi
file valid
```

and for the file without the certain characters:

```
$ read -r a b < invalid
if [[ $a =~ ([-]+.*[,]+|[,]+.*[-]+) ]]; then
  echo "file valid"
else 
  echo "file invalid"
fi
file invalid
```

Now you really have to concentrate on eliminating the spawning of at least a dozen subshells where you call `cut` 3-times, `sed` 7-times, `paste` once and then `cat`. While it is good you are thinking through what you need to do, and getting it working, as mentioned in my comment, any time you are looping, you want to eliminate the number of subshells spawned to the greatest extent possible. I suspect as @Mig answered, `awk` will be the proper tool that can likely eliminate all 12 subshells are replace it with a single call to `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use awk for this all part since you want to test fields and create a string with concatenated fields. Awk is perfect for that.

But here is a small script which shows how you could just test your file's first line:

```
if [[ $(head -n 1 file.csv | awk '$1~/-/ && $1~/,/ {print "MATCH"}') == 'MATCH' ]]; then 
  echo "yes"
else 
  echo "no"
fi
```

It looks overkill when not doing the whole thing in awk but it works. I am sure there is a way to test only one regex, but that would involve knowing which flavour of awk you have because I think they don't all use the same regex engine. Therefore I left this out for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: can you describe how you would use `awk` and provide an example?